# Sticky keys with external keypad

Tags: terminal, keyboard, numlock

I've defined my modifier keys (Shift, Alt, Ctrl) as sticky in terminal using `loadkeys` and the corresponding keymap definition. They behave as expected with the standard keyboard, but they are not sticky when used with the external keypad.

The usual way, when you press the modifier key together with another key, works correctly.

Why?

The keypad is a simple Genius keypad.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that the behaviour is affected by the state of NumLock. If NumLock on the main keyboard is OFF, and the external NumLock is ON (or  vice versa), the keypad sends extra keycodes for each keypress. E.g. for key "5", there are six events:
NumLock pressed & released
KP_5 pressed & released
NumLock pressed & released

This apparently destroys the sticky behaviour.

Tested in Manjaro 18.1. This problem seems to affect the terminal only, when tested under KDE (with sticky keys activated in System Settings) it did not occur. But I don't know about other DEs.